# Transition from activity class to fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

Code in Activity class

```
public void showHomePage(View view) {
        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
        fragment.getParentFragment();
    }
```

I want to switch from Activity class to Home Fragment class. But I am getting this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a007c (com.example.tripist:id/container) for fragment Fragment{a779e36} (17ab85dc-c825-4c86-9e04-cd96dd74f27b) id=0x7f0a007c}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is `R.id.container` an XML layout file pertaining to your Fragment?

Comment: is this the first fragment transaction in this activity, or there is another succeeded transaction?

Comment: I want to switch from empty activity to a fragment opened on bottom navigation view activity.

Comment: R.id.container isn't pertaning to my Fragment @IvanGarza

Comment: Yes, first fragment transaction in this activity. But we come to this activity with a button in the fragment we are trying to pass. This was working without any problems @Zain

Comment: if this is the first fragment transaction, then you need to replace `replace`  with `add` method